# How to change a qty text in Minicart?

Tags: magento2.2, php-7, knockout

How to change **qty text box into dropdown** in **minicart** place `view/frontend/web/template/minicart/item/default.html file` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Override `default.html` to your theme

**From** `vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/minicart/item/default.html`

**TO**`app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_Checkout/web/template/minicart/item/default.html`

**Now change**

```
<input data-bind="attr: {
       id: 'cart-item-'+item_id+'-qty',
       'data-cart-item': item_id,
       'data-item-qty': qty,
       'data-cart-item-id': product_sku
       }, value: qty"
       type="number"
       size="4"
       class="item-qty cart-item-qty">
<button data-bind="attr: {
       id: 'update-cart-item-'+item_id,
       'data-cart-item': item_id,
       title: $t('Update')
       }"
        class="update-cart-item"
        style="display: none">
    <span data-bind="i18n: 'Update'"></span>
</button>
```

To

```
<select data-bind="attr: {
       id: 'cart-item-'+item_id+'-qty',
       'data-cart-item': item_id,
       'data-item-qty': qty,
       'data-cart-item-id': product_sku
       }, value: qty"
       class="item-qty cart-item-qty">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
</select>
<button data-bind="attr: {
       id: 'update-cart-item-'+item_id,
       'data-cart-item': item_id,
       title: $t('Update')
       }"
        class="update-cart-item">
    <span data-bind="i18n: 'Update'"></span>
</button>
```

**Now flush cache and run static:content:deploy to see changes**

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

Comment: Are you remove display:none from button? You should click on update button to update qty after changing qty from dropdown

Comment: Yes.I have removed it.i can update qty.But the updated qty value (selected value) not displayed in qtybox.But that selected value can be updated

Comment: It should be there because `value: qty` already passed in qtybox. Working good in my setup. Please check with private window.

Comment: yes qty is showing...

Comment: How to pass option value dynamically

Comment: how to find corresponding js file @ Patel

Comment: @MahalakshmiM You can find corresponding js file by component name which is defined in a layout file.

Comment: This is my file path...component name is uicomponent./var/www/html/magento22/vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/layout/checkout_cart_sidebar_item_renderers.xml

Comment: How to pass option value dynamically ..i also refer this link..http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html

Comment: for(i=0;i<=4;i++)
{
<option >i</option>}

Comment: You need to create a function with options data in a corresponding js file and call this function in HTML file.

Comment: Yes.In my html file     <p>
    Destination country:
    <select data-bind="options: availableCountries"></select>
</p>
 In js:        viewModel = {availableCountries: ko.observableArray(['France', 'Germany', 'Spain'])};.But i can't showing drop down values

Comment: how to use custom template default.html file value in custom js